# Skyrim sacrifice follower for Boethiah

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements, ps4, xbox-one

I’ve been looking for a solution to this for years and I still have yet to find one. I’ve played through the game on PS4 and just recently started on my Xbox 1 (no mods and I couldn’t use console commands even if I wanted to) I’ve tried every follower, I’ve started new games, I’ve uninstalled and reinstalled. I’m going insane trying to get a follower to activate the pillar of sacrifice but nothing works. Does anyone know of a way to fix this WITHOUT console commands?! If not then please tell me how to install or enable console commands so I can get this stupid trophy? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/answers/300360-boethiahs-calling-how-to-use-pillar-of-sacrifice):

> I had problems with this too. Turns out that you have to use a non-essential follower (meaning that he/she can die). Dark brotherhood followers are invincible. I hired a merc from riften (there is one in windhelm too). After that, I told him to activate the pillar and after a little glitchy-ness on the part of the game's AI pathfinder, my merc was trapped.

Comment: I’ve tried EVERY follower, not even mercenaries work

Comment: You're on a console version of the game. There's nothing to fix. You're doing it wrong. Somehow you are not fulfilling the requirements necessary for its completion. I just want to help. Can you be more specific? What is happening exactly? Are you using the blade of sacrifice? What level is your character? Did you read the book Boethiah's Proving? And speak to Boethia's priestess?

Comment: My follower will not use the pillar no matter how many times I order them, they just say okay and anything else and do absolutely nothing.(I can’t even get them to pick something up off the ground) I can’t use the blade of sacrifice because they won’t use the pillar, my character is level 44, I’ve read the book, and I’ve spoken to the priestess.

Comment: If you can't get any followers to do anything... Including picking up items and so on, it seems it is not related directly to this particular quest. Someone said that it is very important that the follower have their weapons sheathed.

Comment: I’ve tried that as well, the same thing happens.